# How to automatically save zip files in Window firefox

Tags: selenium, firefox, web, automation, selenium-firefoxdriver

I want firefox to automatically save zip file without open/save pop up window like below:

[image]

But "Do this automatically for files like this from now on" option is disabled. 
I also tried setting application type of file to "Save file" in options menu but I do not find any content type as zip type.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the preference on my firefox profile solved the issue.

```
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/plain,application/octet-stream,application/pdf,application/x-pdf,application/vnd.pdf,application/zip");
```